# Can I fulfill somatic casting components if I'm a squirrel right now?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, polymorph, spell-components

I recently lost my form to a polymorph spell and I am a caster so I am trying to figure out what I have open to me. I am currently a [squirrel](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/squirrel).

Somatic components are vaguely defined in the [rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Components):

> A somatic component is a measured and precise movement of the hand. You must have at least one hand free to provide a somatic component.

The [polymorph rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation) also are a little unclear:

> While in such a form, you cannot cast any spells that require material components (unless you have the Eschew Materials or Natural Spell feat), and can only cast spells with somatic or verbal components if the form you choose has the capability to make such movements or speak, such as a dragon.

Does the form of a squirrel allow me to fulfill the somatic requirements for spell casting?

To help clarify this question, looking at the [natural spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/natural-spell---final) feat says something interesting.

> You can complete the verbal and somatic components of spells while using wild shape. You substitute various noises and gestures for the normal verbal and somatic components of a spell.

Since thats the benefit of the feat, I guess the expectation is that normally you cant when wildshaping, which is based on beast shape, elemental body, and so on. All non-humanoid bodies.

Comment: [Possibly related.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/92456/8610)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be mostly up to the GM to decide if you can still cast spells or not while polymorphed, but some forms will never be a problem.

From the [Magic rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph) about polymorph spells :

> When you cast a polymorph spell that changes you into a creature of
>   the animal, dragon, elemental, magical beast, plant, or vermin type,
>   all of your gear melds into your body. Items that provide constant
>   bonuses and do not need to be activated continue to function while
>   melded in this way (with the exception of armor and shield bonuses,
>   which cease to function). Items that require activation cannot be used
>   while you maintain that form. **While in such a form, you cannot cast
>   any spells that require material components (unless you have the
>   Eschew Materials or Natural Spell feat), and can only cast spells with
>   somatic or verbal components if the form you choose has the capability
>   to make such movements or speak, such as a dragon. Other polymorph
>   spells might be subject to this restriction as well, if they change
>   you into a form that is unlike your original form (subject to GM
>   discretion).** If your new form does not cause your equipment to meld
>   into your form, the equipment resizes to match your new size.

An important thing to note : any creature that can take class levels can become a spellcaster, even if its natural form is very far from humanoid. This allows magical beasts of various shapes to develop spellcasting abilities.

Comment: This is basically correct. I'd only add that the assumption should be that you *can't* cast unless you have Natural Spell (for Druids) or your GM allows it. Spellcasting is considered a humanoid thing unless a creature bypasses the requirement of hands; barring Spell-Like abilities which is a pseudo-different case, most non-human caster creature sheets will indicate that they cast as though they had Still Spell with a 0 spell level modifier.